# Google Chrome extenstion - get response body

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to intercept the responses from all of the network requests of the user's browser.

I used `chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted` and got the response headers,

but I don't know how to get the full response body.

I'd be happy if you could help me understand how to do so.

this is my `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "tempName",
  "description": "Temp description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/icon-16.png",
    "48": "/images/icon-48.png",
    "128": "/images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/icon-16.png",
      "48": "/images/icon-48.png",
      "128": "/images/icon-128.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

and this is my `background.js`

```
chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
}, {
  urls: ["<all_urls>"],
});
```

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ddamico.125/intercepting-network-response-body-with-a-chrome-extension-b5b9f2ef9466